# how to add comma after each object and convert into array in javascript react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, json

how can i add comma after each object and convert into array. here's my response data

`{"url":"example.com/john","age":"32"}{"url":"example.com/mike","age":"42"}`

i want this

`[{"url":"example.com/john","age":"32"},{"url":"example.com/mike","age":"42"}]`

i tried with regex but it's converting data into string but i want to render this data

Comment: Are the response objects plain text (string)? Because otherwise I don't know how you can get 2 objects that aren't in array.

Comment: yes it's plain text

Comment: You can converting data into string with regex, and then use `JSON.parse(text)` to convert it to the array.

Comment: Yeah but that's not valid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a little bit of Regex magic to make it valid JSON.

```js
const res = '{"url":"example.com/john","age":"32"}{"url":"example.com/mike","age":"42"}';

const betterJson = `[${res.replace(/}{/g,'},{')}]`;
console.log(JSON.parse(betterJson))
```